# C++ iterate an array of integers whose size is unknown?

Tags: c++

I have the following array:

```
int* myArray = new int[45];
```

If I wanted to iterate each element without knowing the actual size of the array, I would need to use a `for_each`?

If so, then how would you write the `for_each`? I was looking over the following site and reading up on for_each but can't figure out how to put this together.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

---

**Update:** A `for_each` is not a good choice in this case, due to the fact that the size of the array has to be known. vectors are the proper way to accomplish such task. My reason for using arrays, in this case, was for learning purposes. if this was a serious project I would move to something such as Lists/Vectors.

Comment: @Kerrek SB , what do you mean? Its only one line of code :) Or you mean it wouldn't compile because we don't use for_each in this occasion?

Comment: Even one single line can fail to compile if it's not correct...

Comment: @Kerrek SB, what would be the correct way to write that line then?

Comment: `int myArray[45] = { 1, 5, -8, ... };`, or just `int myArray[45];`.

Comment: There are limitless ways to transform an incorrect line of code into a correct line of code...

Comment: You cannot use `for_each` unless you know the size of the array. You might be better off using a `vector` because you *always* know the size of that.

Comment: I understand that a vector is a better way to accomplish this, but my reason for doing this was to learn about the arrays.

Comment: You can use a template function if the array is fixed size, see edit to my answer.

Comment: @Intrus, Fair enough, but you're going to have to use something other than `for_each`.

Comment: @jahhaj i'm checking out the options provided in the answers, but i agree that a for_each may not be the best option here.

Comment: From what I understand of the question, his example of 45 is just because he doesn't know how to describe a dynamic array that grows/shrinks. Eg: `int *myArray;`

Comment: It is an array, don't you always have to specify the size, whether it is a fixed length array or dynamic???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++), you can use "for each."

```
for each(int i in arr) {
    cout << i << ' ' << endl;
}
```

NOTE: This only works in the block of code the array is declared in.

If not, you can also use the new range-based for loop in the C++11 standard.

```
for(int i : arr) {
    cout << i << ' ' << endl;
}
```

If you're intent upon the `std::for_each`:

```
for_each(arr,arr + 10,[] (int i) {
        cout << i << ' ' << endl;
});
```

NOTE: This requires knowledge of the size of the array (in this example, 10).

Comment: I've tried all of them and honestly, this one works flawless:   for each(int i in arr) {
    cout << i << ' ';
}

Comment: @Intrus note that `for each` is an extension, so it is not standard c++. It will make your code unportable to other platforms. This may not be an issue for you, but it is worth knowing.

Comment: @juanchopanza thank you juanchopanza, i will keep this in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

**Note** when the question was first posted, the array in question was declared as

```
int myArray[45];
```

This answer deals with that particular case.

If you have C++11 support, you can use a range based loop:

```
for (int& i : myArray) {
  std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

C++11 also provides [std::begin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end), which you can use with a fixed size array to obtain iterators:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), <func>);
```

Another option, which works for C++03 and you are dealing with fixed size arrays, is to define a function template:

```
// taken a fixed size array by reference and loop over it
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
void array_for_each( T (&a)[N]) {

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    // do something with array elements
    std::cout << a[i] << " ";
  }

}

int main() {
  int a[5];
  array_for_each(a);
}
```

Comment: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ':' token compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors. ?

Comment: @Intrus You have enable c++11 mode in gcc 4.6+ by adding -std=c++11

Comment: @Intrus if you're using gcc, is it an up to date version? Are you compiling with -std=c++11?

Comment: @Intrus sorry, for the C++11 example, you need C++11 support. With GCC you need the flag -std=c++0x. The second example works with C++03.

Comment: @juanchopanza & texasbruce - I'm new to C++ so i wasn't aware of this, i'm just using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Intrus no problem. Unfortunately I don't use VS so I don't know what the C++11 status is. The last option (C++03 function template) should work for you though.

Answer (score 1):

You have described an array of int, not a class that implements a `InputIterator`, which is what the for_each is designed for, even though you can use it to iterate an array, but you need to know the size of the array to iterate it.

If you want to use for_each you need to use a `vector`, `list`, or implement a class that keeps track of the number of elements it contains. IMO it is much easier to just use a `vector`

If you want to just iterate your current array, assuming it is 0 terminated:

```
for(int *value = myArray; *value != 0; ++value)
  printf("%d\n", *value);
```

Or, you can use indexes:

```
for(int index = 0; myArray[index] != 0; ++index)
  printf("%d\n", myArray[index]);
```

IMO the pointer method is cleaner.

This code is still dangerous though, you should either keep track of the number of records in a seperate variable, or use a vector.

Comment: Pointers *are* input iterators.

Comment: @Kerrek SB - the for_each referenced here is a STL template - `<class InputIterator, class T>`

Comment: I suppose he meant range based for loop in c++11, not for_each algorithm.

Comment: @jahhaj - Please notice I corrected my answer, I realised this after your first comment. But what I said still stands, for_each is not valid for this as he is working on a list he doesn't know the size of.

Comment: @Geoffrey: OK, comments deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `for_each`. In this case, you have allocated space for 45 elements in your array, but since it is NULL, you'd probably get a segfault if you tried to do anything. You either need to hold a value of the array, or use something like `sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0])` (which has its own problems).

Anyway, for a `for_each` here, if we actually had 45 elements:

```
 std::for_each(myArray, myArray + 45, <func>);
```

Anyway, this is part of the reason to use vectors: `.begin()` and `.end()` reduces errors with using incorrect indexing.