# Searching an array and returning a pointer to a single element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, iteration

I'm trying to write some functions to handle C++ arrays (for the purposes of this assignment, I'm not allowed to use std::vector - only iostream, algorithm, string, and array).

However, when I run this code, I get two error messages.

> in.cpp:15:25: error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[5]’ to ‘int*’ in initialization
>      int* PointsToArray = &myArray;

This happens when I try to initialize a pointer to myArray. I guess there must be an issue with my pointer/reference declaration syntax, but I've tried "int *PointsToArray" and "int * PointsToArray" and various other ways of spacing around the asterisk, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

The other one is this.

> main.cpp:22:15: error: ‘arr’, 'begin', 'end' was not declared in this scope
>     for(int i : arr)

I borrowed the for(int i : arr) syntax in order to iterate through an array with an unknown number of elements from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11878231/c-iterate-an-array-of-integers-whose-size-is-unknown). The loop worked fine until I added the searchPointer() function; then it threw this error message.

My code is below, please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int searchArray(int array[], int targetInt);
//Iterates through an array & returns index of an element identical to target

int* searchPointer(int* arr, int targetInt);
//Returns a pointer to an element that matches the target

int main() {
  int targetInt = 4;
  int myArray[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int* PointsToArray = &myArray;

  searchArray(myArray, targetInt);
  searchPointer(PointsToArray, targetInt);
 }

int searchArray(int array[], int targetInt) {
  for(int i : arr) {
    if (i == targetInt) {
      int* x = find (std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), targetInt);
      cout << "Your target " << targetInt << " found at index " << x << "\n";
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int* searchPointer(int* arr, int targetInt) {
  for (int i : arr) {
    if (i == targetInt) {
      std::cout << "Target located at " << &targetInt << " in memory\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not the asterisk. It's the ampersand. It does not belong there.

Comment: 2nd question: the variable is declared as `array` not `arr` in `searchArray`.

Comment: Also, just because you saw some other code that read "`for(int i : arr)`" doesn't mean you can blindly copy-paste it in the middle of your own code, and it'll work. Your first problem is that you did not declare any object named `arr`. It's pretty hard to iterate over a container that has never been declared.

Comment: With `&myArray` you get a pointer to the ***array***, not a pointer to the first element. The type of `&myArray` is `int (*)[5]`, which is *very* different from the type `int *` of `PointsToArray`. If you want to get a pointer to the first element, which have the type `int *`, then use `&myArray[0]`, or plain `myArray` as that will automatically translate to `&myArray[0]`. And it his pointer you really should have.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, Sure you can iterate like that.  You just have to declare the array size. E.g. `int arr[5];` `for (auto a : arr) {}`

Comment: Furthermore, for functions the argument declarations `int* arr` and `int arr[]` are *equal* and the same.

Comment: And why are you using `std::find` inside the loop in the `searchArray` function? It makes no sense. Either you use your loop to find the value, or you use `std::find`. Don't use both.

Comment: @SidS Oh. Everyday learning something new. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the name of the array is the address of the first element i think u have to write it like this

int* PointsToArray = myArray;